# how to save opened Excel files in background every 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, autosave

I run a thread to autosave excel files every 5 minutes. When it saves, the saving file(fileA) will be actived . And on the same time , I was editing other file(fileB). 
How can I save fileA in background when I'm using fileB?
Here's my C# code in thread:

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(AutoSaveTime);
    if (isRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            Workbooks files = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks;
            foreach (Workbook book in files)
            {
                if (book.Saved != true 
                           && book != Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook)
                {
                    book.Save();
                }
            }
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, but why not just [change the autosave time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Help-protect-your-files-in-case-of-a-crash-551c29b1-6a4b-4415-a3ff-a80415b92f99) in Office?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! AutoRecover in Office is not simple enough for my customers. They just need AutoSave function ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
wbook.SaveAs("c:\\temp\\blah", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wbook.Close();
```

Or, put this snippet of VBA code in ThisWorkbook Module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "SaveThis"
End Sub
```